# i have used keypad in my program its not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have two textfields which are of type `UITextField`. 
I have two buttons *click* and *cancel*.

The idea is to enter two numbers and it will navigate to next view. This View should display those two numbers.

The problem is if I click on the textfield one then the keypad is responding; when I click return it does not jump to the next field.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{[textField resignFirstResponder];return YES;}
```

Comment: Have you connected all the outlets and actions? Please also post the rest of the code.

Comment: adding more tags might increase your attention!

Comment: We don't mind the occational spelling or grammer mistake, but we expect you to at least try a little! This is just plain sloppy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect `UITextFiled` **Delegate** from `nib` or programeticuly like  this image:

[image]

or

other way is programmatic like in your `viewDidLoad` method or `viewWillAppear` method:

```objc
Yourtxtfild.delegate = self;
```

**EDIT**
for jumping AnotherView Use this textfiled delegate method:-

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {

  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  //you can set your textfiled string in to globle Variable and use it in another viewController
  YourViewCntroller *objViewController = [[YourViewCntroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewCntrollernib" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objViewController animated:YES];

 }
```

Comment: i used that delegate standards.and its nice too

Comment: sir ummm i need the keypad everytime have to resign and by clicking next textfield it should be respond?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delegate of the textfield as the object of the class where you have written the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method.

Comment: you can post full of description answere other wise you can give answerer as a comment thank you

Comment: @nitin: That is the full answer.Setting the delegate would solve the problem. For a basic question like this, the answer is more than enough.   And answering in comments is not recommended. And if you are worried about reputation I've given you an upvote.

Answer (score -1):

@Ragavan : You are just resigning the first textfield, but you are not making the other textfield to respond. So, use the code below as reference to make it work.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: without connect delegete you can not resign your Textfiled keybord

Comment: sir one more question how to pass a string to next view simply sir?

Comment: @Nitin : but, he didn't even mentioned about connection delegates in his question. see the code pasted by him. With the code he copied he can't jump to next textfield by clicking "return" button even he has correct connections in the .xib file.

Comment: @SaiJithendra:before i was using condition to resign the keypad.but using delegates it resigning perfectly..

Comment: @Raghavan : It will resign. But, how did you make it to jump to next textfield without touching the 2nd textfield and without using becomeFirstResponder ?

Comment: I am not saying other answers were wrong. What I am saying is without any of these answers, you can't make the whole functionality to work as you required including jumping to the next field

Comment: saijithendra.gogineni@gmail.com